# MVVM pattern javascript

Tags: javascript

Can anyone share me a code or example of `MVVM pattern` in JavaScript **without** Knockout.js. I want to implement MVVM pattern in my project, but without using `Knockout.js`.

**Update**

The Application i am working is not Web Based and has limitation of using Knockout.js. I liked the pattern anyway, but to implement i need a better pure JS example.

Answer (score 2):

[Microsoft has an example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine//hh297451.aspx) that uses jQuery. (found by a quick google search)  You might share why you don't want Knockout.js so people can post an example that is more useful to your needs.

Comment: One reason is you'll have a more complete understanding of what is happening in the system, if you code the pattern your self.   

I've had nothing but problems with frameworks,  dependencies getting outdated,  almost impossible to change the structure of the system because no UML is provided, documentation is often poor at best (even with the most popular frameworks).  So until documentation gets to a level that is comprehensive, and appropriate software engineering diagrams are provided with frameworks, its best to steer clear I think.